# How to Reuse Logic Without Copy/Pasting Blocks of Code - C#

Tags: c#

My project reuses the code below multiple times with only a few variables changing. I've noted the values that change with e.g. ***value***.

```
  if (comboBox1.Text == ***"Most recent first"***)
            {
                string dgvconn = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\CW\CW\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                string sql = "select * from Records where UserID = @userID Order By ***Date Desc***";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dgvconn);
                SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", currentUserID);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                connection.Open();
                dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Records");
                connection.Close();
                recordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                recordsDataGridView.DataMember = "Records";
            }
```

How can I use this same logic, with different values, without copying and pasting the if statement multiple times?

Comment: Wouldn't you just make it a method that receives parameters?

Comment: Add some parameters to your method and use their values where you wrote `**...**`.

Comment: Yes sounds right but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: We neither, as you didn´t show enough context - in particular the methods signature.

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) could be a good starting point

Comment: so I make a method such as:      Method a (do I pass paremeters in here)? And how do I run the method while changing these paremeters?

Comment: By providing the parameters? How should we know which values you want for your combo-text and your query.

Comment: Don't see why people downvote me on a badly worded question I'm obviously In need of help why not just help me word it right?

Comment: Im not asking u to know what paremeters I want im asking u to help me with the structure

Comment: Where do you receive the parameter of comboBox? The comboBox will have predined values?

Comment: The data access (insert, select and so on...) should be elsewhere. It has nothing to do with the UI (`comboBox1` let me think we are in the Human-Machine Interface). It should be in another class that handle the DB (or, even better, in another layer). Seperation of concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me you want something like:

```cs
private void foo(string matchText, string sortBy) {
    if (comboBox1.Text == matchText)
    {
        string dgvconn = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\CW\CW\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "select * from Records where UserID = @userID Order By " + sortBy;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dgvconn);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", currentUserID);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Records");
        connection.Close();
        recordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds;
        recordsDataGridView.DataMember = "Records";
    }     
}//foo

//Call the method
foo("Most recent first", "Date DESC");
foo("Most recent last", "Date");
foo("By Username", "User");
```